# Multiplying integers the long way

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I'm trying to create long int multiplication function. In math for multiplying 2 numbers for example 123 X 456, I do:

```
(12 * 10^1 + 3)( 45 * 10^1 + 6) = 
(540 * 10^2) + (72 * 10^1) + (135 * 10^1) + 18 = 15129
```

I created a small program for this algorithm but it didn't work right.

I don't know where my problem is. Can you help me to understand and correct that?

Tnx

```
int digits(int n) {
    int digit = 0;
    while (n>0){
        n/=10;
        digit++;
    }
    return digit;
}

long int longMult(long int a, long int b) {
    long int x,y,w,z;
    int digitA = digits(a);
    int digitB = digits(b);

    if((a==0) || (b==0)) {
        return 0;
    } else if (digitA < 2 || digitB < 2) {
        return a*b;
    } else {
        int powA = digitA / 2;
        int powB = digitB / 2;

        //for first number
        x = a/(10^powA);
        y = a%(10^powA);

        //for second number
        w = b/(10^powB);
        z = b%(10^powB);

        return ( longMult(x,w)*(10^(powA*powB)) + longMult(x,z) +
                 longMult(w,y)*(10^(powA*powB)) + longMult(y,z));
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << digits(23) << endl; // for test
    cout << longMult(24,24); // must be 576 but output is 96
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems to defeat the purpose of the long multiplication to store the values in a long int.  If instead you used a vector<int>, with one element for each digit, you could have arbitrary precision multiplication.

Answer (score 4):

The expression

```
10^powA
```

does a bitwise exclusive or, and doesn't raise 10 to the power of powA, as you appear to expect.

You may want to define something like

```
long powli(int b, long e) {return e?b*powli(b,e-1):1;}
```

Then instead you can use

```
powli(10,powA)
```

---

Edit:  There is also a problem with the way the values are combined:

```
    return ( longMult(x,w)*(10^(powA*powB)) + longMult(x,z) +
             longMult(w,y)*(10^(powA*powB)) + longMult(y,z));
```

Look into the maths, because multiplying the exponents makes little sense.

Also the combinations of adjustments to values is wrong, eg (10*a + b)(10*c + d) = 10*10*a*c + 10*a*d + 10*b*d +b*d.  So check on your algebra.

Comment: using a lookup table for powers of 10 is better, except for the case of arbitrary precision

Comment: Yes, a lookup table would be faster, but I thought the recursive style would better suit the style of the rest of the code, which is about doing things in a slow, but conceptually interesting way.